# Are there any rules about damaging body parts in WoD?

Tags: combat, world-of-darkness

I have heard of a rule with no quotation given (so presumably a house rule) that implies that 3+ health levels worth of lethal (or aggravated) damage dealt in one attack may severe a limb, or simply render it useless. This can be indirectly supported by the rules for regrowing a limb, such as the one that ghouls use (from page 501 of V20 Corebook, page 501).

Grave's Decay path of Necromancy level 3 power, Wither, implies that 2 levels of aggravated damage are enough to render the limb useless, but that may possibly be just a case for that particular Discipline.

**Are there any WoD rules that allow severing limbs by non-supernatural means? If not, what other passages of official books may imply a possible house rule to manage that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an official supplement (for 2nd ed, I think), [*World of Darkness: Combat*](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/53268/world-darkness-combat) that covers combat and weapons in detail; it does cover those scenarios in Appendix One: Hit Locations, p.89 and following pages.

Comment: Also we use a good home rule that states that no more then 3 letal damage may be dealt to a limb. Of cause, there is pain shock which may be fatal but we're talking mostly about vampires, mages and other creatures which can withstand it. It would be very strange to die from one hit to a hand, even if it is very powerful.